# How can i implement this in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I query a table based with HABTM relationship while providing additional conditions in CakePHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602227/how-do-i-query-a-table-based-with-habtm-relationship-while-providing-additional)

Pls help me implement this in cakephp

```
table safari:
id
name
duration

table region:
id
name

table regions_safaris:
safari_id
region_id

select s.name
from region r, safaris_regions sr, region r, safari s
where r.name='yourRegion'
and sr.region_id=r.id and s.id=sr.safari_id and s.duration=5;
```

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about where you are struggling

Comment: Also, you have the region table aliased twice as r in your query

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what specifically you are struggling with, but you can make your query clearer by separating the join conditions from the selection criteria:

```
select s.name
from safari s 
inner join regions_safaris sr on(s.id=sr.safari_id)
inner join region r on(sr.region_id=r.id)
where r.name='yourRegion' 
and s.duration=5;
```

Your query also had the mistake of using safaris_regions instead of regions_safaris, and aliasing the regions table twice.

Answer (score 1):

you should change the region table to regions, and safari table to safaries to make it work with cakephp. after setting up the relations in the model, you would use a find.

```
//safaries_controller.php 
$this->Safari->find('all', array('fields'=>'Safari.name', 'conditions'=>array('Region.name'=>'yourRegion'));
```